# How do I click on this item using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to automate the download of report using selenium. To get to the page where the report is I have to click on an image with this code

```
<div class="leaflet-marker-icon single-icon-container running hover asset leaflet-zoom-hide leaflet-clickable" tabindex="0" style="margin-left: -22px; margin-top: -41px; width: 44px; height: 44px; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(525px, 238px, 0px); z-index: 238;"><div class="icon-value" lid="219058"></div></div>
```

I tried with

```
wtg = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
    "leaflet-marker-icon single-icon-container running hover asset leaflet-zoom-hide leaflet-clickable")
wtg.click()
```

but nothing happens.
There are 7 elements with the same class, and a unique "id " tha looks like `lid="219058"` but I dont know how to select that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the best practice when building web scrapers is to always use xpath, since xpath can apply all the filters (id, class, etc) in a more flexible way (in some cases though, performance in selenium might be decreased).

I recommend you check this article on how to write xpaths for various needs: https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/xpath-writing-cheat-sheet-tutorial-examples/

For your particular use case, I would use:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@lid="219058"]')
```

This will actually click on the inner div (notice how the lid is actually inside the nested div). If you wish to click on the outer div you can use:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@lid="219058"]/parent::div')
```

I again recommend you to learn Xpath syntax and always use it, it is way easier to manipulate than the other selenium selectors and is also faster in case you ever choose to implement a C compiled html parser such as lxml to parse the elements.

Comment: Well technically XPATH is the slowest locator and the engine for that is different in each browser making it very brittle. I always recommed ID,NAME if it's there but otherwise CSS _SELECTORS are faster and more  compatible.

Comment: Apparently you are correct @ArundeepChohan, sorry for the mistake. As I'm used to working with lxml (which is a faster parser) that handles xpath very well, I'm editing the response.

Answer (score 2):

`leaflet-marker-icon single-icon-container running hover asset leaflet-zoom-hide leaflet-clickable` contains multiple class names while `driver.find_element_by_class_name` method intends to get a single class name.
I can't give you a correct locator for this element since you didn't share the page link, however if you wish to locate that element based on these class names combination you can use CSS Selector or XPath as following:

```py
wtg = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".leaflet-marker-icon.single-icon-container.running.hover.asset.leaflet-zoom-hide.leaflet-clickable")
wtg.click()
```

Or

```py
wtg = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='leaflet-marker-icon single-icon-container running hover asset leaflet-zoom-hide leaflet-clickable']")
wtg.click()
```

Also you should use `driver.find_element_by_class_name`, not `driver.find_elements_by_class_name` since `driver.find_elements_by_class_name` will give you a list of web elements, not a single web element that can be clicked directly.
Alternatively you can use the first index inside the list of received web elements as described by FLAK-ZOSO

Comment: Thanks but it didn´t work. The page is voe.vestas.com, but you need password to enter.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `driver.find_elements_by_class_name()` returns a `list`.

You have to do something like this when using this `get/find` method:

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('class')[0] #If you want the first of the page
```

---

In your case you need to use the `css_selector` because you have multiple classes, like suggested by @Prophet.
You can also use only one of the classes and simply use the `class_name` selector.

In your case, if you need the first element of the page with that class, you have to add `[0]`.

Comment: I´m getting this error `NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".leaflet-marker-icon.single-icon-container.running.hover.asset.leaflet-zoom-hide.leaflet-clickable"}`